# Prestashop dynamic Weight

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

I wonder if I could show dynamic weight of each product combination on my product page? Now I'm using something like this:

```
{l s='Weight: ' js=1}{sprintf("%1\$u",$product->weight)}&nbsp{Configuration::get('PS_WEIGHT_UNIT')}
```

But it not working with product combinations - it only show base product weight. I tried to duplicate quantity idea but it doesnt work.

Big thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this as you have given little information. What I assume you mean is you want to loop over each item and then provide the weight?

```
$weight = 0;
foreach ($product) {
    $weight = $product->weight + $weight;
}
```

Obviously my answer isn't going to be correct in terms of syntax but without more information It's hard to guess, plus I don't have the reputation to comment in order to ask.

Comment: Hello Anthony. I think I need to add some ajax call and receive some information from product.php file but unfortunately I have no idea how should it work. There is similar topic on Prestashop forum: [CLICK](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/68051-mod-display-the-declinated-weight-on-product-page/) but it's very old and don't work with 1.6.1.1.

Comment: Have you seen this at all? http://addons.prestashop.com/en/front-office-features-prestashop-modules/14571-show-weight-on-product-page.html / It works on Prestashop versions 1.3.x.x -> 1.6.x.x

Comment: Yes I have but I think 30 £ for such a mod is way to much. And this is not the main reason why I dont want to buy it. I just want to learn how to make it for my own :) But anyway, thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't assist you.